Pseudopotential PBE and PBEsol
For my calculation I need to use PBEsol in ABINIT for DFT. Can someone guide me how can I know my pseudopotential is a PBE or PBEsol, also how can I use it Abinit? Do I need to use any specific variable in my input file? For example ixc? Thank you so much.

I strongly recommend you to go through the tutorials at the Abinit website.
Answering your questions:

"...Can someone guide me how can I know my pseudopotential is a PBE or PBEsol...":
You can open the pseudo file in a text editor and look inside. For example, below is a part of the carbon PBE and PBESol pseudopotentials files where you can see the info you are looking for:

For the PBE pseudo:
   <PP_INFO>
         UPF file from ATOMPAW code with following input
           C 6                                       ! Definition of material
           XC_GGA_X_PBE+XC_GGA_C_PBE scalarrelativistic loggrid 2001
           2 2 0 0 0 0                                 ! Max. n per angular momentum: 4s 3p 3d
           2 0 2.0
           2 1 2.0
           0 0 0
           c
           v
           v
           1                                           ! Max. l for partial waves basis
           1.5 1.3 1.5  0.6                            ! r_PAW radius
           y
           3.0
           n
           y                                          !
           3.0
           n                                           ! Do we add an additional d partial wave ? no
           Vanderbilt
           2 0.5 ultrasoft                                       ! Scheme for pseudopotential (l_loc=3, E_loc=0Ry)
           1.4                                         ! r_c matching radius for first  s partial wav
           1.4                                         ! r_c matching radius for second s partial wave
           1.5                                         ! r_c matching radius for first  p partial wave
           1.5                                        ! r_c matching radius for second p partial wave
  </PP_INFO>

For the PBESol pseudo:
   <PP_INFO>
         UPF file from ATOMPAW code with following input
           C 6                                       ! Definition of material
           XC_GGA_X_PBE_SOL+XC_GGA_C_PBE_SOL scalarrelativistic loggrid 2001
           2 2 0 0 0 0                                 ! Max. n per angular momentum: 4s 3p 3d
           2 0 2.0
           2 1 2.0
           0 0 0
           c
           v
           v
           1                                           ! Max. l for partial waves basis
           1.5 1.3 1.5  0.6                            ! r_PAW radius
           y
           3.0
           n
           y                                          !
           3.0
           n                                           ! Do we add an additional d partial wave ? no
           Vanderbilt
           2 0.5 ultrasoft                                       ! Scheme for pseudopotential (l_loc=3, E_loc=0Ry)
           1.4                                         ! r_c matching radius for first  s partial wav
           1.4                                         ! r_c matching radius for second s partial wave
           1.5                                         ! r_c matching radius for first  p partial wave
           1.5                                        ! r_c matching radius for second p partial wave
  </PP_INFO>


"...also how can I use it Abinit?..." The full information about how to use it can be obtained here. You need to put all your pseudopotentials files in a folder and then add them in your input using the pseudos keyword. For example, for a system with aluminum and gallium (you need to check the path of these files):


pseudos "al.psp8, as.psp8"


"...Do I need to use any specific variable in my input file?..." Yes, see point above.

"...For example ixc?" The variable ixc (Index of eXchange-Correlation functional) controls the choice of exchange and correlation:



Controls the choice of exchange and correlation (xc). The list of XC functionals is given below. Positive values are for ABINIT native library of XC functionals, while negative values are for calling the much wider set of functionals from the ETSF LibXC library (by M. Marques), available at the LibXC home page Note that the choice made here should preferably agree with the choice made in generating the original pseudopotential, except for ixc = 0 (usually only used for debugging). A warning is issued if this is not the case. Unfortunately, pseudopotential (or PAW) generators for hybrid functionals and mGGA are currently under development, so that one usually uses GGA or LDA pseudopotentials instead. The error should be limited when GGA or LDA pseudopotentials with semi-core states are used. Still this is a non-controlled error. Moreover, the choices ixc = 1, 2, 3 and 7 are fits to the same data, from Ceperley-Alder, and are rather similar, at least for spin-unpolarized systems. The choice between the non-spin-polarized and spin-polarized case is governed by the value of nsppol (see below).

